# War file does not work with maven complier source 17

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, java-17

I am using JDK 17.0.3 in eclipse (2022-04). below is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>longlist</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    
    <properties>
        <spring.version>5.3.18</spring.version>
        <spring-security.version>5.6.2</spring-security.version>
        <spring-data-jpa.version>2.6.3</spring-data-jpa.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.6.7.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate-validator.version>6.2.3.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
        <mysql-connector.version>5.1.36</mysql-connector.version>
        <commons-dbcp.version>1.4</commons-dbcp.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <junit.version>3.8.1</junit.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
        
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
       
        
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
      
      
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20080701</version>
</dependency>
      
      
      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
    <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.18</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    

</project>
```

If I export war file in my eclipse and deploy it in Tomcat 9, it fails. But If I change "maven complier source" and "maven complier target" to 1.8 instead of 17 and then I export war file in eclipse and deploy in Tomcat, war file works. I cannot understand why it is not working working when I use maven complier source / target 17 in pom.xml.

Below are Maven details

```
Apache Maven 3.8.5 (3599d3414f046de2324203b78ddcf9b5e4388aa0)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.8.
Java version: 17.0.3, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Fil
\jdk-17.0.3
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: "does not work" means that If I try to start my application I get an error " 
FAIL - Application at context path [/testproject] could not be started".

Comment: I donot get this error If I use java 1.8 in my pom.xml. After deployment, my application is easily started and I donot get any error.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and update with complete error log.

Comment: Your pom.xml misses the `<build>` section and there the `maven-compiler-plugin` entry where you define the source and target code level.